# Use Python script to programmatically animate the pose bones of Rigify's Base Human Rig

Tags: python, animation, bones, rigify

I am using MediaPipe and OpenCV to capture the pose of a person and want to animate the Base Human rig offered by Rigify add-on according to the captured pose in Blender. First of all, I wrote an animate() function to test whether a pose bone object was correctly programmatically animated:

```
def animate():
    bone = bpy.data.objects["rig"].pose.bones['upper_arm_fk.L']
    print(bone.name)
    displacement = [3, 3, 3]
    euler_angles = [math.radians(30), math.radians(30), math.radians(30)]
    bone.rotation_euler[0] = euler_angles[0]
    bone.rotation_euler[1] = euler_angles[2]
    bone.rotation_euler[2] = euler_angles[1]
    bone.location[0] += displacement[0] * scale_factor_x
    bone.location[1] += displacement[2] * scale_factor_z
    bone.location[2] += displacement[1] * scale_factor_y
    bone.keyframe_insert(data_path="location", index=-1)
    bone.keyframe_insert(data_path="rotation_euler", index=-1)

i = 0
for i in range(100):
    animate()    
    i += 1
```

Although the "upper_arm_fk.L" pose bone was correctly accessed, the result was that there was no movement of the bone. Blender was on Object mode, and I tried setting the mode to Pose but it did not work either. I also tried removing bone.keyframe_insert(), but to no avail. I am wondering how I can correctly program the animation of Base Human rig's pose bone objects. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The base human has an IK/FK switch for each arm.  If it is set to FK, you can move the IK target, but the bones won't move.  Could this be your problem?

Comment: to clarify, there will be no animation above, apart for on first run,  since there is no use of `i` in animate, it will set the location on same frame 100 times. Quite possibly it fails 99 times. Or to put another way: Are you getting the keyframe set on the frame you are on on only?  If a bone is connected location will have no effect. Same If the bone is in another rotation mode.  Pass `i` and use `keyframe_insert("datapath", frame=i)`